# .net core webapi causes iis application pool to shutdown

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

**Background**:

I'm building a .net core webapi does practically nothing more than checking if a given URL exists and returns the result. If a URL exists and is a redirect (301, 302), the api follows the redirect and returns that result as well. The webapi is called by an SPA which does an api-call for every given url in a checkrequest-queue. So, if someone adds 500 urls to the queue the SPA will loop through it and will send 500 calls to the API – something I could improve upon.

**The problem:**

My IIS application pool is being shut down on a regular basis due to high CPU usage and/or memory usage:

`A worker process serving application pool 'api.domain.com(domain)(4.0)(pool)' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.`

The only way to get my API going again is to *manually restart the application*. I don't think the operations performed by the API are that demanding, but I surely must be doing something wrong here. Can somebody help me please? The code called by the SPA is:

```
var checkResponse = new CheckResponse();

    var httpMethod = new HttpMethod(request.HttpMethod.ToUpper());
    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(httpMethod, request.Url);

    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

    var httpResponseMessage = await httpClient.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
    checkResponse.RequestMessage = httpResponseMessage.RequestMessage;
    checkResponse.Headers = httpResponseMessage.Headers;
    checkResponse.StatusCode = httpResponseMessage.StatusCode;

    switch (httpResponseMessage.StatusCode)
    {
      case HttpStatusCode.Ambiguous:
      case HttpStatusCode.Found:
      case HttpStatusCode.Moved:
      case HttpStatusCode.NotModified:
      case HttpStatusCode.RedirectMethod:
      case HttpStatusCode.TemporaryRedirect:
      case HttpStatusCode.UseProxy:

        var redirectRequest = new CheckRequest
        {
          Url = httpResponseMessage.Headers.Location.AbsoluteUri,
          HttpMethod = request.HttpMethod,
          CustomHeaders = request.CustomHeaders
        };

        checkResponse.RedirectResponse = await CheckUrl(redirectRequest);
        break;
    }
```

The Action on my ApiController:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CheckRequest request)
{
  if (!ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
  }

  var result = await CheckService.CheckUrl(request);

  return Ok(result);
}
```

Comment: Application pool is only shut down when the worker processes crashing often. Revise your description above to include more information on that part.

Comment: The worker processes don't seem to be crashing, the problem seems to be the memory `A worker process serving application pool '....com(domain)(4.0)(pool)' has requested a recycle because it reached its private bytes memory limit.`

Comment: Seems like your API gets stuck in an infinite redirect loop leading to memory spike and therefore forced to be shutdown by IIS.